# Why were there no fish korbanot?

Tags: korban, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, fish

I realize that the Rambam indicates that there is no particular significance to which animals were designated by the torah for korbanot. I further realize that many of the mystical commentaries, Ramban chief among them, take umbrage with Rambam's approach.

My question is are there any commentaries who speak specifically about why there were no korbanot brought from fish or other (kosher) sea creatures